# Как ввод ReadLine перевести в int?

Tags: c#

Сделать вот так

```
string number = Console.ReadLine();
if(number == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

Естественно не получается, а почему? Метод `Console.ReadLine` возвращает только `string`, а если работать с `int`, то как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string number = Console.ReadLine();
if(Convert.ToInt32(number) == 3)
{
      Console.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

класс [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx), думаю, нагуглите сами

к тому же в вашем случае будет работать и так:

```
if(number == "3")// и  так: if(number == 3.ToString())
{
      Console.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

---

а если написать что-то вроди:

```
public bool _(Action<string> action, string arg)
// а лучше public bool _<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)
{
    action(arg);
    return true;
}

public void _(bool flag)
{
    return;
}
```

то можно будет писать в "сишном" стиле

```
void Main()
{
    ...
    _(number == 3 && _(Console.WriteLine, "ok"));
}
```

но чёт я отклонился от темы=)

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if(number == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string x = Console.ReadLine(); int xa = Convert.ToInt16(x);`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]