# как сделать выбор между способами ввода?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. У меня есть 3 способа ввода (рандомный по возрастанию, по спаданию и просто рандомный), как мне сделать, чтобы я мог выбирать между этими способами. Если можно, покажите кодом или хотя-бы псевдокодом.

Comment: Ввод чего и куда?

Comment: @Андрей сгенерировать массив из чисел 3 способами. И мне нужно, чтобы я мог выбирать каким именно способом я хочу это сделать. Это в консоли если что.

Comment: Ввод бывает пользовательский - с клавиатуры, мыши, тачпада, трекбола, гироскопа... Вы видимо говорите о каком-то другом способе ввода. Возможно, вы имеете ввиду 'seed'?

Comment: А, это... Пишете в консоли "введите способ ввода 1. Фыва 2. Фждло 3. Ождло" и опрашиваете, какую клавишу ввёл пользователь. Разумеется, пользователь может ввести другую цифру (или даже не цифру), поэтому нужно проверять ввод. Console.WriteLine() и Console.ReadLine() вам в помощь. Hint: можете тупо поискать слово ReadLine по метке c# -- наверняка увидите подходящие образцы кода ) Вот [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461773/213987) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/94495/213987).

Comment: Добавьте подробностей в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Накатал простейший вариант.

Сначала определим метод ввода

```
interface IEntryMethod
{
    int Read();
}
```

Потом напишем клиента

```
class Client
{
    IEntryMethod _entryMethod;

    public Client(IEntryMethod entryMethod)
    {
        _entryMethod = entryMethod;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var item = _entryMethod.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше добавим парочку методов ввода

```
class RandomEntryMethod : IEntryMethod
{
    static Random rand = new Random();
    public int Read() 
    {
        return rand.Next();
    }
}

class ConsoleEntryMethod : IEntryMethod
{   
    public int Read()
    {
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Ну, и как все это юзать

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Select entry method (random/console):");

    IEntryMethod method;

    switch (Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "random":
            method = new RandomEntryMethod();
            break;
        case "console":
            method = new ConsoleEntryMethod();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        return;         
    }

    var client = new Client(method);
    client.DoStuff();
}
```

Код на ошибки не проверял, смотрите на него как на концепт